# Smack API, how to update my ChatBox after processing message

Tags: api, smack

I am trying to use an object instancied by a class "ChatBox". I want to apply the method DisplayMessage inside the method "processMessage"

```
  public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message )
    {                
        if(message.getType() == Message.Type.chat){
            System.out.println(chat.getParticipant() + " says: " + message.getBody());
            chatBoxLinked.MessageDisplay(message.getBody());
         }

    }
```

The messages can't be displayed. How can I do ?

Thank you very much

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use listview and add your message into it.